# How to see PreparedStatement's SQL string?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

When we create a PreparedStatement we use '?' chars to then be replaced by setted parameters.

How can we see the final SQL string after these parameters are set?

Comment: See: [How can I get the SQL of a PreparedStatement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382532/how-can-i-get-the-sql-of-a-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way (that works with any JDBC driver) is to use [log4jdbc](http://log4jdbc.sourceforge.net). It's a proxy that wraps the driver, creates a readable SQL string by combining the SQL and its parameters and logs it, then passes the SQL and parameters on to the underlying driver.

Answer (score 11):

There is no final SQL string, the version with placeholders is what is actually sent to server. The data is sent completely separately from it as you execute queries on the prepared statement.

You can log the string with placeholders, and then each dataset individually.

Your code could combine them in the log to an actual SQL string if that's what you want:

```
String query = "SELECT a FROM b WHERE c = ?";

...

pstmt.setString(1, "asd");
logSQL( query, "asd");
```

`logSQL` would then actually log `"SELECT a FROM b WHERE c = 'asd'"`. [Could be that someone has actually implemented this before...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553105/995876)