# How Can I Sanitize MySQL Query Parameters In Esper

Tags: esper

I am using Esper 5.0 and need to perform a query on data from a relational database. This is in my case a MySQL database connected via JDBC. Now I would like to formulate an EPL query on the data from the database. Hence, my query is similar to this one:

```
String parameter = "any"; // untrusted (!) parameter from some user input
String mySqlQuery = "SELECT `sth` FROM `mytable` WHERE `att` = " + parameter;
String query = "select sth from sql:myDB ['" + mySqlQuery + "']"
```

Now how can I sanitize the untrusted parameter which is then send to my MySQL database? The [Esper documentation](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#histdata_join) says that the query is basically passed to the database software unchanged. So what can I do? I came up with four ideas:

1. **Using EPL substitution parameters:** Does not work, because it is not supported by Esper in SQL expressions.
2. **Using EPL variables:** It should be possible to define a variable via something like `epService.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().addVariable("parameter", String.class, parameter);`, then use the syntax `` "SELECT `sth` FROM `mytable` WHERE `att` = ${parameter}" `` for the MySQL query. Esper should replace the variable with the respective value. It is not nice to define a global variable for it, although one could again remove it with `epService.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().removeVariable("parameter", true);` afterwards. But much more important: That also does not sanitize the untrusted parameter and does not make it safe to pass it to the database, right?
3. **Sanitizing the parameters on the Java side:** Queries on the Java side should be done via `PreparedStatement`. Since it is [technically impossible to get a MySQL query string out of a `PreparedStatement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382561/719023), this is not an option. I do not think that there is another safe way to sanitize a parameter passed to a database on the Java side.
4. **Defining all the constraints on the EPL side:** One could probably just do a `` SELECT * FROM `mytable` `` without defining any constraints in order to select everything from the MySQL database and then define the constraints via EPL and use a [`EPPreparedStatement`](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#api-prepared) for it. Is this the proper way to go? I fear that this is not really performant, because a lot of entries are read from the MySQL database which are not needed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would it work with the statement object model API? That API gives you complete control over all parts of EPL.

Comment: Well... I do not know :-) I am pretty much new to Esper. If you added an example showing how to use it with a MySQL statement and how to sanitize the parameters with it, I would be very thankful.

Comment: BTW why don't you create a Stackoverflow account? :) Thanks for all the help here with [#esper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esper)