# how Can I get the full query that a PreparedStatement is about to execute?

Tags: java

Currently my

```
preparedStatement.toString()
```

is showing output as `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6@30bf28`

but i want to print the query for debugging purpose.I am using postgresql database and using jboss datasource connector for connection.

So, please guide me to how to print the preparedstatement query.

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382532/how-can-i-get-the-sql-of-a-preparedstatement)