# get PreparedStatement query from Derby

Tags: java, log4j, derby, slf4j, log4jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a database, run a query and print out the query. So far what I have works but I need to get the output and assign a particular part of it to a `String`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger.getGlobal().setLevel(Level.INFO);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            connect();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ID = ?";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //String usedSql = "query should  go here";
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                try {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            disconnect();
        }
    }
```

I'm using [log4jdbc](http://dev-answers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/quick-start-to-tracing-jdbc-sql.html) to spy on my queries.

At the moment I get logged output like:

```
594 [main] DEBUG jdbc.foo  - 1. Connection.new Connection returned   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
608 [main] DEBUG jdbc.foo  - 1. PreparedStatement.new PreparedStatement returned   com.example.Test.main(Test.java:63)
608 [main] DEBUG jdbc.foo  - 1. Connection.prepareStatement(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ID = ?) returned net.sf.log4jdbc.PreparedStatementSpy@7d70d1b1  com.example.Test.main(Test.java:63)
608 [main] DEBUG jdbc.foo  - 1. PreparedStatement.setInt(1, 1) returned   com.example.Test.main(Test.java:64)
608 [main] DEBUG jdbc.foo  - 1. PreparedStatement.setMaxRows(1) returned   com.example.Test.main(Test.java:65)
609 [main] DEBUG jdbc.sqlonly  -  com.example.Test.main(Test.java:66)
1. SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ID = 1
```

I want to assign `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ID = 1` to `usedSql`. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What does `preparedStatement.toString()` give you ?

Comment: @Berger: `net.sf.log4jdbc.PreparedStatementSpy@7d70d1b1`

Comment: I think this is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382532/how-can-i-get-the-sql-of-a-preparedstatement)

Comment: No, it hasn't. No idea why that answer was marked as correct when all it does is say **it's impossible** when clearly it's not since I've done most of it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a `preparedStatement.toString()` will give you the query (incl. bound parameters). But it depends on the actual implementation of the `PreparedStatement` (with the PostgreSQL impl this works, for example).

You mentioned that `preparedStatement.toString()` returns `net.sf.log4jdbc.PreparedStatementSpy@7d70d1b1` for you. I'm not familiar with *log4jdbc* but I looks like `PreparedStatementSpy` is wrapping your actual `PreparedStatement`. To get it from your `preparedStatement` try something like

```
if(preparedStatement instanceof PreparedStatementSpy)
     usedSql = ((PreparedStatementSpy) preparedStatement).getRealStatement().toString();
```

**Edit**: since you are using *Derby* a simple `toString()` won't do. A way around this could be to use `PreparedStatementSpy.dumpedSql()`, which will return the same string *log4jdbc* uses for logging. Unfortunately its a *protected* method and you have to use reflection:

```
if (preparedStatement instanceof PreparedStatementSpy) {
    Method m = PreparedStatementSpy.class.getDeclaredMethod("dumpedSql");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    usedSql = (String) m.invoke(preparedStatement);
}
// omitted exception handling
```

Comment: PreparedStatement implements [java.sql.Wrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html) which might be another way to gain access to the target statement.

Comment: I'm using derby embedded because it's the fastest. I'm not sure what `PreparedStatementSpy` is but log4jdbc acts as a proxy between the database and your application to provide additional information about the communications between them.

Comment: @Hooli see my update for an example that could work with `Derby`

Comment: Thanks, pity that Derby doesn't offer the `toString()` option or some sort of alternative, I guess this will have to do.

Comment: Sounds like you could log an enhancement request with the Derby community for your idea about improving PreparedStatement.toString