# Are ResultSet update{ColumnType} methods vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, sql-injection, bluemix-app-scan

A security scan made by AppScan source flags that the input has to be validated (Validation.Required) on the line `uprs.updateString` in the code below:

```
    PreparedStatement statement = 
        conn.prepareStatement (query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ...
    ResultSet uprs = statement.executeQuery ();
    ...
    // Update DB ColumnA with input coming from client
    uprs.updateString ('ColumnA', unvalidatedUserInput);
    ...
    // Updates the underlying database
    uprs.updateRow();
```

I assume that the intention behind this is to avoid SQL injection attacks, but I'm not sure whether that is possible in that scenario.

Questions: Are SQL Injection attacks possible through these JDBC methods? How does JDBC implements this under the scenes? Would this be another false positive reported by AppScan?

Comment: Entirely safe in general database drivers. Only when the SQL string is constructed you are in trouble. Or other vulnaribilities: when the stored data is outputted in HTML and contains javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about bluemix-app-scan, but I'm providing my explanation here. (*This is my assumption based on the below tests and code pasted*)

I ran a test code to check this (in **H2 DB**) 
value of **testName** String : `(select 'sqlInjection' from dual)`

1. Using *`createStatement`* **(Not-Safe)**:

   ```
   String query = "update TEST_TABLE set TEST_CHAR = " + testName + " where ID = 1";
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
   statement.executeUpdate(query);
   ```

   **Output:** TEST_CHAR in DB was *sqlInjection*.
2. Using *`ResultSet` of `createStatement`* **(Safe in H2 DB)**:

   ```
   String query = "select * from TEST_TABLE where ID = 1";
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   ResultSet executeQuery = statement.executeQuery(query);
   executeQuery.next();
   executeQuery.updateString("TEST_CHAR", testName);
   executeQuery.updateRow();
   ```

   **Output:** Surprisingly TEST_CHAR in DB was *(select 'sqlInjection' from dual)*.
3. Using *`PreparedStatement`* **(Safe)**:

   ```
   String query = "update TEST_TABLE set TEST_CHAR = ? where ID = 1";
   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
   statement.setString(1, testName);
   statement.executeUpdate();
   ```

   **Output:** Expected - TEST_CHAR in DB was *(select 'sqlInjection' from dual)*.
4. Using *`ResultSet` of `prepareStatement`* **(Safe in H2 DB)**:

   ```
   String query = "select * from TEST_TABLE where ID = 1";
   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   ResultSet uprs = statement.executeQuery();
   uprs.next();
   uprs.updateString("TEST_CHAR", testName);
   uprs.updateRow();
   ```

   **Output:** Expected - TEST_CHAR in DB was *(select 'sqlInjection' from dual)*.

**Back to Questions:**

> Are SQL Injection attacks possible through these JDBC methods?

**Maybe.** It depends on the database driver that you're using.
**How?** :
The reason SQL Injection failed in my result set update was because H2 database internally uses `PreparedStatement` to update the row when `ResultSet.updateRow()` is invoked.

```
public void updateRow(Value[] current, Value[] updateRow) throws SQLException {
    StatementBuilder buff = new StatementBuilder("UPDATE ");
    ...
    buff.append(" SET ");
    appendColumnList(buff, true);
    ...
    appendKeyCondition(buff);
    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(buff.toString());
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
       ...
        v.set(prep, j++);
    }
    setKey(prep, j, current);
    int count = prep.executeUpdate();
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if all DB drivers in java implemented `updateRow()` method using `preparedStatement` or not. However it's clear that this is left to the driver and if bluemix is suggesting you to add a validation here, I suggest you follow that :)

> How does JDBC implements this under the scenes?

Well, as shown above this is driver specific. However there is a good explanation on how `PreparedStatement` handles it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382561/1925997).

> Would this be another false positive reported by AppScan?

I don't think this is false positive (but in cases like H2 DB it is) but you'll never know if all database drivers implemented this securely.

**Edit -**
Even PostgreSQL and [MySQL](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.25/com/mysql/jdbc/UpdatableResultSet.java#UpdatableResultSet.updateRow%28%29) use PreparedStatement to handle this.

```
public synchronized void updateRow() throws SQLException
{
    ...
    updateStatement = ((java.sql.Connection) connection).prepareStatement(updateSQL.toString());
    ...  
    updateStatement.executeUpdate();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is very thorough.