# Printing PrepareStatement using oracle JDBC Driver

Tags: java, oracle

this might be a simple question but am stuck here. I want to print preparestament to check what string it is passing before execution. Is there any way to print it. Here what I tried till now.

```
PreparedStatement Pdst1=con.prepareStatement("select distinct fyear from tblparam");
System.out.println(Pdst1.toString());
```

Here am getting output as 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@c8211c
But I want to print statement. Kindly help.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2382532/3260495

Comment: You could search on the database side, though. Just add a comment to the SQL `con.prepareStatement("select distinct fyear /*myQuery1*/ from tblparam") and search the cursor cache 'SELECT * FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text LIKE '%myQuery1%';`