# How to get SQL query from JDBC in Apache Derby?

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

I'm using [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/). I want to extract the query from the JDBC program. I know that the questions in these lines have been asked ([How can I get the SQL of a PreparedStatement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382532/how-can-i-get-the-sql-of-a-preparedstatement)). But this question is specific to Apache Derby.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
          "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
           WHERE SALARY BETWEEN ? AND ?");
stmt.setInt(1, 1000);
stmt.setInt(2, 100000);
```

**Edit**
After this point in the above code snippet is there way to get the actual query **without executing** in the DB?

I do not want to execute `PreparedStatement` in the DB. i.e without using `stmt.execute() or stmt.executeQuery()`

Comment: @GordThompson you should have read the question fully before marking it as duplicate. I had asked for getting the query sql from `Derby`. But **without executing the query to the database**. I do not find the answer which I am expecting in the question which you have given.

Comment: What does "get the actual query without executing in the DB" mean? The actual query is right there in your code: `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE SALARY BETWEEN ? and ?`

Comment: @BryanPendleton I know that query already present in the code. What I meant is without calling `stmt.execute() or stmt.executeQuery()` in the code can I get the query?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the answer is the link you mentioned.

> Using prepared statements, there is no "SQL query" :
>
> You have a statement, containing placeholders
>   it is sent to the DB server
>   and prepared there
>   which means the SQL statement is "analysed", parsed, some data-structure representing it is prepared in memory
>   And, then, you have bound variables
>   which are sent to the server
>   and the prepared statement is executed -- working on those data
>   But there is no re-construction of an actual real SQL query -- neither on the Java side, nor on the database side.
>
> So, there is no way to get the prepared statement's SQL -- as there is no such SQL.
>
> For debugging purpose, the solutions are either to :
>
> Ouput the code of the statement, with the placeholders and the list of data
>   Or to "build" some SQL query "by hand".

Comment: There are other solutions like this one [too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26228133/10362432)  in the same question. But I want the solution for Derby

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but whats about statement.getGeneratedKeys() ?

Comment: @Curious That is specific to the MySQL driver. In most databases (and drivers), the parameters are **never** combined with the prepared statement. The statement is prepared with parameter placeholders, and a collection of parameter values is sent at execute. At best they may simulate it for debug output (and that may be tricky, because that may not necessarily be syntactically correct).