# How to inject parameter into a string inside query string with namesJDBCTemplate?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a query in format

```
namedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("""
select * from table
where column = 'somethins :param'
""", new MapSqlParameterSource('param', someValue), someReturnType);
```

How can i make it inject the param value into the string?

This is a simplified case. Actual usecase uses a function on DB side to construct a complex query, all im giving it is a where clause and params for the where clause:

```
namedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("""
    select myfunc($$%s$$)
    """.formatted(getFilterClauseFromDB()), params, someReturnType);
```

When the formatting does its work it should look something like this

```
 namedJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("""
        select myfunc($$AND val1 = :val1 and val2 = :val2 $$)
        """, params, someReturnType);
```

where params is a Map<string, object> of parameters parsed by a generic parameter parsing system to put them into correct format. But the namedJDBCTemplate does not map parameters to :val1 and :val2 for some reason. Function intenrally runs a postgres crosstab function. Even if i do away with my function the issue remains. I need to inject parameters into a string that is inside SQL since crosstab accepts queries in the format of string.

Somehow i need to get the params placed into the filterclause that is a string that is built on the runtime. Is there a way i can do it? Currently it throws error `The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0`

Comment: Now if there would be a aptly named [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) that would just do that.

Comment: It wonnt inject if it is a pat of the string. Like `val = :val` will work but `val = ':val'` gives me error. As in the string i need to inject into is also a string.

Comment: If hte parameter is properlly marked as string you don't need the quotes, the JDBC driver will act accordingly. I suspect you are trying to outsmart the JDBC driver

Comment: Like i said. This is simplified example. In real usecase i have something like `'AND val1 = :val1 and val2 = :val2'` that gets passed to myfunc as a string parameter.

Comment: Then replace it yourself. Instead of adding variables add the actual value. Yes that is prone to SQL injection. But either do that or don't use Strings like this.

Comment: cant allow sql injection danger. How would you handle a situation where the expected result is a product of crosstab with dynamic amount of columns where each column is user defined on runtime and you need to use this result of crosstab as a filter for another query?

Comment: I would generate a normal query and not invoke a function. Just run the query.

Comment: But what if all the data you need exists in DB in multiple tables and colelctind the data for crosstab is non trivial?

Comment: That query is still somewhere, regardless of anything the query needs to be written. If you do that in a function/procedure or Java with JDBC it is still the same query.

Comment: There is tho 1 thing. I might be able to buuild it on Java side, but main issue is. Crosstab takes queries as strings so the issue remains. And i need crosstab since i need a pivot table.

Comment: What is crosstab what you are referencing?

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-the-crosstab-function-in-postgresql/ a function in postgresql to create pivot tables.

Comment: Now that is some crucial piece of information you want to include in your question.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53006570/2696260) you can obtain the SQL String from a PostgresSQL statement. So you can make it a 2 part process. First prepare the query you want to pass to the `crosstab` function, get it as a `String` then prepare the second query.