# How to log a PreparedStatement?

Tags: logging

I need to log all PreparedStatements in my application. So far I've done logging of chosen queries by hand, but I have hundreds of them and adding logging for them would be a terrible job to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging PreparedStatements in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218113/logging-preparedstatements-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using plain JDBC, not any ORM, since it's a different story then.

There's a library called [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/), it's sufficient to add it to your classpath and add it to your JDBC URL just after "jdbc":

```
jdbc:log4jdbc:[rest-of-your-regular-URL-here]
```

and change your driver class to:

```
jdbc.driverClass=net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy
```